Creating and Configuring a SSL certificate for Novice
I'm a complete novice at configuring OpenSSL; I've located the OpenSSL executables on my Windows computer by means of git on Windows.
Although I do not know where to begin to create an SSL certificate for a site that will be accessed and require a login and password that is where the SSL will play its part for the client in sending the client the login and password just as long as the client as the SSL certificate for that site. Otherwise, if the client does not have the certificate, the site will show the user to enter their login and password.
I've searched for how to setup and configure OpenSSL but most of the sites only tell how to install it, which I do not require this information. I'm ready to run the command required to do that of which I'm asking in this question.

Why use OpenSSL to create a self-signed certificate, which nobody will trust with regards to a public website at least, since only scammers use self-signed TLS certificates for public websites. Let’s Encrypt is a much better solution

@Ramhound: They're asking about client certificates. Nobody uses a public CA for those.

As @grawity_u1686 mentioned. Its a client certificate and it's only for all of my devices which will be connecting too when either inside our outside of my LAN.

What configuration are you looking for? The certificate issuance part or the validation part?

@grawity_u1686 Where to begin and what must I modify with regards to files so that the SSL certificate knows which site its to be used with.
In other words, what must I execute to create the SSL certificate with OpenSSL, unless there is something better to create secure SSL certificates. when those files are created, of those created files what must I change as to enter in the login and password for the site which the SSL certificate is to be used with ?

@grawity_u1686 - “SSL certificate for a site” - Suggests public and private certificate would be required, authentication with self-signed certificates is still suspect, unless your using a GPG keyring. The details of using it only within a LAN wasn’t in the question.


what must I execute to create the SSL certificate with OpenSSL

I would not recommend using the openssl CLI tools for certificate creation. Use Easy-RSA or XCA or something else that already has good certificate templates. (Windows Server has an AD-integrated Certificate Authority feature.) You can use openssl ca for this (there are tutorials out there) but you'd be almost building the certificates from scratch, and that's a bit too much to explain for day 1, considering that alternatives exist.
The general steps are:

Create a (self-signed) CA certificate.
Copy the CA certificate to your web server (without private key), and configure the web server to trust it for "client certificate" authentication.
Use that CA certificate to sign each user's SSL client certificates.
Copy the user certificates (with private key) to user PCs and install in web browsers.

Note that SSL 'client' certificates use a slightly different template from 'server' certificates. There is a lot of overlap, of course, and many public 'server' certificates are actually issued from a dual client/server template, but you should still consider them mostly distinct. Client certificates can actually be a bit simpler – e.g. usually you don't need subjectAltName.

when those files are created, of those created files what must I change as to enter in the login and password for the site which the SSL certificate is to be used with

This would be handled by your web server. Search for "client certificate" or sometimes "mTLS".

Apache httpd: SSLVerifyClient and SSLCACertificateFile
Nginx: ssl_verify_client and ssl_client_certificate

Note that the certificate will not auto-fill any forms. Instead, the webapp itself needs to look for certificate details in headers from the web server (e.g. $_SERVER["SSL_something"] in PHP) and automatically log the user in according to their certificate's CN.

Thanks, if there is a anything you want to add that may help just append it.

It will be easier if you ask more specific questions – e.g. separately about some problem you have creating an internal CA, separately about configuring Nginx or such, separately about recognizing that from your webapp, etc.

I understand, three part question. If I ask how to do something, but don't know how it's done then I have to how it's done first.
